# how to use sql query using a stored procedure in visual studio and then use the return to make a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

I am very new to all of this. I am trying to display a table from my sql database in a form on visual studio, I have a stored procedure that selects a row from said table and I checked the procedure and it works. the problem is taking it and from what i understand change it from enum to list.

```
public List<PersonModel> Get_All_People()
        {

            List<PersonModel> Output;

            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
            {
                Output = connection.Query<PersonModel>("Trial DB.dbo.spGet_All_People").ToList();
            }

            return Output;

        }
```

The "PersonModel" is a class and "Trial DB" is my database name and "db" is a variable carrying my connection string.
I tried calling other procedures the same way and they work so I think the problem is in the syntax of the
`Output = connection.Query<PersonModel>("Trial DB.dbo.spGet_All_People").ToList();`

The way I call it from my form is

```
private List<PersonModel> AllPeople = new List<PersonModel>();

        private void LoadPeopleListData()
        {
            foreach (IDataConnection db in GlobalConfig.Connections)
            {
                AllPeople = db.Get_All_People();
            }
        }
```

I am using the `foreach` because I have two connections that i use, sql and text.
My project doesn't show any errors but when i try to run it gives me this error from visual studio 2019
**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'**
and it highlights this line
`Output = connection.Query<PersonModel>("Trial DB.dbo.spGet_All_People").ToList();`
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Put brackets around your DB name:
`[Trial DB].dbo.spGet_All_People`. I think the stored procedure has invalid syntax.

Comment: Thank you @Junior it worked, it's weird tho because i didn't need to do this before in any of the other

Comment: sorry @viveknuna I didn't think it was the Connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put brackets around your DB name: `[Trial DB].dbo.spGet_All_People`